# What code in my inizializer file can run delayed workers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, command-line, delayed-job

I am using a Mac OS running *Snow Leopard* 10.6.8, Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and the DelayedJob gem. I would like to run some "command lines"/"tasks" from an inizializer so to start delayed workers.

In order to do that in my `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb` file I am trying to state the following:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  system 'rake jobs:work'
elsif Rails.env.production?
  system 'RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop'
  system 'RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -n 2 start'
end
```

However, the above code will start a lot of `ruby` processes and those rapidly slow my machine so I have to restart that. The remote machine run *Linux Ubuntu* 10.4.

**How can I properly state that code so to run delayed workers?**

In any case I think that, since on the local and remote machine are running two different Operating System, "command lines"/"tasks" should be different, as well...

Comment: Since your setting it in your initializers it will start running every time an instance of your application spawns.  This is very problematic in production if you have say 5+ instances running. 

What you should really look into is starting delayed job during your deployment process with capistrano or chef.  How do you deploy to production?

Comment: @JDutil - I deploy by using the Capistrano gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using an initializer this should be done during deployment as your initializer is run for every instance of your app that is spawned.

Since you use capistrano I typically handle this like so:

in `config/deploy.rb`:

```
require 'delayed/recipes'

after 'deploy:symlink', 'delayed_job:restart'
```

Since your wanting to spawn 2 workers this could be done by setting the delayed_job_args:

```
require 'delayed/recipes'
set :delayed_job_args, "-n 2"
after 'deploy:symlink', 'delayed_job:restart'
```

Comment: One more thing: Why I have to `require 'delayed/recipes'`? What do those do? What are those for?

Comment: The require delayed/recipes statement is loading a capistrano recipe from the delayed_job gem.  Essentially it loads this file: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/recipes.rb if you decide to write your own recipe instead like I show in the second code block you shouldn't need the require statement as your writing your own to use instead.

Comment: Oh interesting I just learned something new from looking that file up..  You can actually set the number of workers with the normal recipe I'm glad I just looked that file up.  I'll update the post with the how to do it.